# Continuous $f:[x_1,x_2]\to\mathbb{R}$ is not "1-1" if there are local maxima at interval ends

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f:[x_1,x_2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f$ has a local maximum at $x_1$ and at $x_2$. Show that $f$ is not "1-1".

I have thought of using EVT, but I seem unable to prove that $f$ cannot be "1-1". It is sure, however, that reductio ad absurdum has to be used.

Comment: Hint: assume w.l.o.g. that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$. Since $x_2$ is a local maximum, can you show $f$ isn't injective?

Comment: @JonathanY. I cannot see how to do that?

Comment: Hint #2: for sufficiently close $x<x_2$ we know $f(x)\leq f(x_2)$. Clearly, if equality is ever achieved, we're done. Otherwise, there exists $x\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x)<f(x_2)<f(x_1)$. So?

Comment: @JonathanY. IVT in $[x_1, x]$, so there exists $x'\in (x_1, x)$ such that $f(x')=f(x_2)$, but $x_2>x'$, which is a contradiction if $f$ was injective. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you've got it! Consider answering your own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume with loss of generality that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

Suppose that $f$ was injective.

Since $x_2$ is a local maximum, there exists at least one $x_1<x_3<x_2$ such that $f(x_3)\leq f(x_2)$.

- If $f(x_3)=f(x_2)$, this is a contradiction, since $x_3<x_2$.
- If $f(x_3)<f(x_2)<f(x_1)$, the Intermediate Value Theorem in $[x_1, x_3]$ implies that there exists at least one $x_4\in (x_1, x_3)$ such that $f(x_4)=f(x_2)$, which is again a contradiction, since $x_4<x_3<x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ has a local maxima at both $x_1,x_2$ so $\exists \delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $f(x_1)>f(x)\forall x\in [x_1,x_1+\delta) $ and $f(x_2)>f(x)\forall x\in (x_2-\delta ,x_2] $.

So $f(x)$ first decreases and then increases.

*Graphically:* The graph of $f $ first decreases attains a minimum value and then again increases to attain its local maximum value.(Note that it attains the minimum value because of its continuity).

So there must exist two points $x_1<a<b<x_2$ such that $f(a)=f(b). $

Comment: However, this is based solely on the graph, which by itself is not a complete proof. If you could provide us also with another proof other than the above posted, I would appreciate it much!!